# Текст налезает на изображение HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, img

Всем привет, текст налазит на изображение. Должен стоять справа от изображений. Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо

```css
.description-container{
 width: 78.5%;
 display: flex;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.img-block{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.img-ud{
 display: flex;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.img-ud img{
 width: 60%;
 padding: 5px;
}
.contact{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="description-container">
        <div class="img-block">
            <div class="img-ud">
                <img src="http://i5.otzovik.com/2016/02/20/2999864/img/22859706.jpeg" alt="">
                <img src="http://i5.otzovik.com/2016/02/20/2999864/img/22859706.jpeg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="img-ud">
                <img src="http://i5.otzovik.com/2016/02/20/2999864/img/22859706.jpeg" alt="">
                <img src="http://i5.otzovik.com/2016/02/20/2999864/img/22859706.jpeg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="desc-block">
            <div class="contact">
                <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
                <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
                <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="map"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас изображения выходят за пределы блока `img-ud` поскольку не указано свойство `flex-wrap: wrap` + изображения не адаптивны

```css
.description-container {
  width: 78.5%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.img-ud {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  //margin-left: 20px;
}

.img-ud__item {
  padding: 5px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.contact {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.desc-block {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="description-container">
  <div class="img-block">
    <div class="img-ud">
      <div class="img-ud__item"> <img src="http://i5.otzovik.com/2016/02/20/2999864/img/22859706.jpeg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="img-ud__item"> <img src="http://i5.otzovik.com/2016/02/20/2999864/img/22859706.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-ud">
      <div class="img-ud__item"> <img src="http://i5.otzovik.com/2016/02/20/2999864/img/22859706.jpeg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="img-ud__item"> <img src="http://i5.otzovik.com/2016/02/20/2999864/img/22859706.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="desc-block">
    <div class="contact">
      <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
      <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
      <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а почему изображения в твоем случае не стоят по 2?

Comment: Потому что вы задали им ширину в 60%.

Comment: в твоем ответе то нету ширины

Comment: а все, спасибо.